# Apache Rewrite URL to index.php variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, windows-xp, httpd.conf

I am trying to migrate a website from one host to another. The current host has very old versions of PHP, Apache and MySQL. I have installed the same versions of all on a test Win XP VM. The website's htaccess looks like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /  

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com [NC] 

   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^(sales) index.php?main_page=page&id=2
    RewriteRule ^(support) index.php?main_page=page&id=3
    RewriteRule ^(about_me) index.php?main_page=page&id=4
    RewriteRule ^(help) index.php?main_page=page&id=5
    RewriteRule ^(site_map) index.php?main_page=site_map
```

Could anyone tell me what options I would need to enable in httpd.conf to get this to redirect correctly? At the moment, the main page shows, but any link clicked from the menu bar on the home page, shows an error. For example, **The requested URL /sales was not found on this server.**

Answer (score 1):

edit .htacces file like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing forward slashes and a $

```
RewriteRule ^(sales) index.php?main_page=page&id=2
```

should be

```
RewriteRule   ^(/sales)$ /index.php?main_page=page&id=2
```